# Remove close button on specific application

Tags: skype, metacity

I would like to remove the close button only on selected applications.
Is it possible?

My expected result would be deactivating Skype's tray ugly-icon and removing the close button from his window, so i reduce to possibility to accidentally close the app.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to do this.  The simplest option would be a tiny application that is just runs a transparent window and is set to always on top and not decorated.  Place this window on top of the anticipated location of your skype client.

You could also replace the icon.